# MotionEvent - How to get back to home position?

Tags: android

At the beginning I'm not quite good in english so please forgive me any mistakes.

I made simple app which moves a white circle from home position (100,100) to any other in limited RelativeLayout (200x200). All I want to do is to move that circle to home position (100,100) after I stop touching screen. I'm using MotionEvent actions but when I set anything in ACTION_CANCEL or ACTION_UP (for example x=100; y=100;) it move circle even when I'm still touching or moving it.

I will be very grateful for any help.

code:

```
public class Dott extends View {

    private static final float RADIUS = 20;
    TextView X;
    float x = 100;
    float y = 100;
    float Pressure1, Pressure2;
    public static float kurwaX, kurwaY;
    private float initialX;
    private float initialY;
    private float offsetX;
    private float offsetY;
    private Paint backgroundPaint;
    private Paint myPaint;

    public Dott(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        backgroundPaint = new Paint();
        backgroundPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        myPaint = new Paint();
        myPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        myPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            x=event.getX();
            y=event.getY();
            initialX = x;
            initialY = y;
            offsetX = event.getX();
            offsetY = event.getY();
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            x = initialX + event.getX() - offsetX;
            y = initialY + event.getY() - offsetY;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            break;
        }
        return(true);   
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        int width = canvas.getWidth();
        int height = canvas.getHeight();
        canvas.drawRect(0,0,width,height, backgroundPaint);     
        if (x>=200) {
            x=200;
        }
        else if (x<=0) {
            x=0;
        }
        if (y>=200) {
            y=200;
        }
        else if (y<=0) {
            y=0;
        }       

        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, RADIUS, myPaint);
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `invalidate()` should not be part of the `draw`-method. Instead it should be called any time you change the position of the circle by touch-event. So your `onTouchEvent`-method should look like this:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    int action = event.getAction();
    switch(action)
    {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        //do something (such as setting the coordinates)
        invalidate();
        break;
    case ...:
        ...
        invalidate();
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Additionally returning allways true isn't good because then no other Touch-Handler can intercept the touch since returning true means "event is handled". so it would be better to return true only if an event is detected in which you actually want to do something (i.e. ACTION_DOWN, MOVE, UP)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the circle to always start at `(100, 100)`, and then follow your finger as you drag it around, then go back to `(100, 100)`, try doing something like this:

```
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        x = event.getX();
        y = event.getY();
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        x = event.getX();
        y = event.getY();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        x = 100;
        y = 100;
        break;
```

make sure you have a break after the `ACTION_MOVE` case.

Answer (score 0):

under MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE there is no break statement so it is complemet to Action_UP and Action_cancel